# Is it acceptable to throw from IComparable.CompareTo()?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, icomparable

Example (Currency is an enum):

```
public struct MoneyQuantity: IComparable<MoneyQuantity>
{
    public Currency Currency { get; }
    public decimal  Amount   { get; }

    public MoneyQuantity(Currency currency, decimal amount)
    {
        Currency = currency;
        Amount   = amount;
    }

    public int CompareTo(MoneyQuantity that)
        => Currency == that.Currency ?
            Amount.CompareTo(that.Amount) :
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't compare quantities of money in different currencies");
}
```

Is this acceptable? Or is it expected that when a type is IComparable, any two instances of the type should be comparable and no exception should be thrown if client code tries to compare them?

Comment: I think this code looks fine, I think the question is if the other developers consuming MoneyQuantity expect 1 thing or another. If I supply a MoneyQuantity where Currency is Euros and a MoneyQuantity where Currency is USD for example, have I been told it would do a conversion to compare them? You give the information about why it's an invalid operation so this looks perfectly legal and explains what's going on to me.

Comment: You could make currencies comparable, so that, for example, all dollar amounts compare less than all pound amounts -- obviously no two amounts of different currencies should be equal. The question is whether or not such a thing would be useful to callers. Arguably, by the time they've obtained a set of currencies that are incomparable, and are trying to do comparisons, something has already gone wrong. Whether throwing an exception or performing some comparison that's consistent is better depends on your use cases. For display purposes, for example, any sort may be better than none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd count it as a problem, rather than unacceptable. Obviously something that throws on `Sort` or any operation that calls into `CompareTo()` (including things that users might not realise calls into it) are going to be less useful that things that "just work", so the possibility would have to be well documented (the error message helps). But on the other hand, it's better than something that "just works" in a way that may not be quite correct.

You are forcing users to either avoid such comparisons or work out a way to do the comparison themselves (e.g. converting to a consistent currency for comparisons) but that also forces them to make sure they do so on term that work for them (e.g. doing such conversions according to the rates that they would actually be using). That is likely the best you can do on balance.

Answer (score 1):

I have played around in the past with modelling "units", such as currency here, as types and then you'd make `MoneyQuantity` generic on one of those types. (You can do lots of fancy playing around to try to ensure that the types it gets parameterized on are only the currencies you want to support). This immediately prevents the problem (because a `MoneyQuantity<Dollar>` would be comparable to other `MoneyQuantity<Dollar>`s but not to `MoneyQuantity<PoundSterling>` or any other type).

E.g. the `Console.WriteLine` line below fails to compile but the rest is fine:

```
using System;

namespace PlayAreaCSCon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d = new MoneyQuantity<Dollar>(1);
            var p = new MoneyQuantity<PoundSterling>(1);

            Console.WriteLine(p.CompareTo(d));
        }
    }
    public abstract class Currency
    {
        protected Currency() { }
    }
    public class Dollar : Currency
    {
        public Dollar() : base() { }
    }
    public class PoundSterling : Currency
    {
        public PoundSterling() : base() { }
    }
    public struct MoneyQuantity<TCurrency> : 
           IComparable<MoneyQuantity<TCurrency>>
           where TCurrency : Currency, new()
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; }

        public MoneyQuantity(decimal amount)
        {
            Amount = amount;
        }

        public int CompareTo(MoneyQuantity<TCurrency> that)
                => Amount.CompareTo(that.Amount);
    }
}
```

(I'm not entirely happy with making `Dollar` and `PoundSterling` in the above constructable when they're more serving as markers, but it allows us to use the `new()` constraint to prevent `MoneyQuantity<Currency>`s being a valid type)

If using C# 7.2 or later, you can make `Currency`'s constructor `private protected` as one of the guards against people creating rogue `Currency` types.

Of course, this may not fit all parts of your problem area so don't just jump in and do this without weighing the pros and cons. Of course, F#'s units look much better but I've not used them in anger.

Comment: This would be a good fit for some use cases, although I think not mine. It does push consumers of your class into having to be aware of the type parameter.

Comment: @Hammerite - yeah, I initially wrote it as a comment. It kind of expanded into an answer. I recognize it won't be a good fit for all (hopefully you see that in there). I just think it's an interesting way to try to use the type system to enforce this kind of constraint (that different currencies aren't directly comparable). You can introduce a non-generic base class below `MoneyQuantity` which allows some runtime flex, but you have to give up `struct`. As also hopefully clear, there's tradeoffs here if you want to use the type system to do this.

Comment: @Hammerite - I have sometimes considered proposing a language feature along the lines of `domain Money:decimal units {Dollar, PoundsSterling} supports (Equality, Maths);` and having the compilers spit out all of the boilerplate that would make it work. It looks nice to me (and why I've experimented with things like in my answer) but giving truly compelling use cases (rather than "wouldn't this be nice") is where I fall down.